# JMeter export script in C#

Tags: scripting, jmeter

Can we export a JMeter recording into a C# or Java script?
I need to customize the code script generated at the backend, just like we do in Load Runner or Selenium.
I tried to find it but there is no option or may be I am missing it.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no option for this.

With JMeter to customize a Plan you use the following:
- CSV Data Set for input data
- Post Processors to extract data from responses and expose them as variables
- ${varName} that you have extracted to replace data in HTTP Sampler

To debug your script you use View Results Tree.